# Can't open emulator 8.1 through Visual Studio 2013 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-emulator

I am having a problem being able to run the Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB from Visual Studio. When I go to deploy any of my projects, my emulator appears, Loading is displayed on the screen for about 30 seconds, then it says Windows Phone OS Is Starting.... and it sits there for about 5 minutes. Then it says Windows Phone OS Is Shutting Down and it shuts down and disappears from my screen.

My Hyper-V is enabled and working. I checked to see if I can start the emulator from Hyper-V Manager instead of Visual Studio and it starts up fine without any problems. It is also 100% usable as well. Unfortunately I can't deploy my apps from VS this way, or at least I haven't figured out how to if there is a way to do so.

Comparing the 2 ways of starting the emulator, from the Hyper-V Manager I see my computer is constantly using the CPU to a max of 10%. And memory allocated to it is about 33MB. When running the emulator from VS the CPU is at 0% for the entire time that the message "Windows Phone OS Is Starting...." is displayed. Memory usage is the same.

At first I thought my computer didn't have the resources to run the emulator until I was able to run it from the Hyper-V Manager.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I am the only one in my class who has the issue and no one has a solution for it yet.

I am running Windows 8.1 (On a Mac through Bootcamp), Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Antivirus software and firewall interfere with Emulator start up. Try disabling Antivirus\firewall and see if you can run the Emulator